# Centering input box and icon button

Tags: css, input, icons, center

I want to center vertically both of the input box and the icon button.
I tried flexbox justify-content and align-content and it still not working.
Is there any way in css that i can do this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: share your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap them with a container div which will have `display:flex;`. It is always good to use `flex-direction` property, in your case that would be `row`.

Then to align the items vertically use `align-item:center;`. And if you want them to be horizontally centered as well then add `justify-content:center;` to the css of  `.container` in the example below.

I have used an image as well as a font-awesome icon for search-icon alongside the input box, Since you have not mentioned in the question which one you are using.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
.container input{
  line-height:80px;
  margin:0 5px;
}
.container img{
  height:50px;
  margin:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  <img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: @Lan Mai  Please do accept my answer if it solves your problem. You know click on the checkbox on the left of my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Jezz... Your answer is so good! And I did checked the box :)
Thank you very very very much @kittyCat !

Comment: @Lan Mai   Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

To the parent element of the input box and icon button, add the property line-height and set its value equal to the height of the parent of the input and icon button.

Example: If they both are inside of a div and the height of that div is 40px, add the property line-height to that div and set it to 40px.

Comment: nice approach! Thank you very much :)